# How can I stop multiple routes matching in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to MVC but I'm trying to create an MVC Web API and I'm having a problem with routing.

I'm trying to work with the following URL patterns:

```
/api/venue/1999          // doesn't work
/api/venue/1999/images/  // works
```

The second URL pattern works fine, but if I try and access the first one, I get an error which says:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>   VenuefinderWebAPI.Models.Venue Get(Int32) on type
>   VenuefinderWebAPI.Controllers.VenueController System.String[]
>   Images(Int32) on type VenuefinderWebAPI.Controllers.VenueController

I'm not sure if it's my routing which is wrong (multiple matches) or something in my controller class.  How can fix this?

In my webApiConfig I have this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "VenueImages",
    routeTemplate: "api/venue/{venueID}/images/",
    defaults: new { controller="Venue", action = "images" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "VenueDefault",
    routeTemplate: "api/venue/{venueID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Venue" }
);
```

VenueController.cs has:

```
// GET api/venue/5
public Venue Get(int venueID)
{
  // code
}

and 
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("images")]
string[] Images(int venueID)
{
   // code
}
```

Comment: They look redundant... What action do you think the 2nd route should call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

Change your Venue controller:

```
public string Get(int venueID)
{
    // code
}

[HttpGet]
public string[] Images(int venueID)
{
    // code
}
```

Change your routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "VenueDefault",
    routeTemplate: "api/venue/{venueID}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Venue", action = "get" },
    constraints: new { venueID = @"\d+" }
);
```

*Added Mike's constraint to the route.

--- What the above does ---
The route matches urls, where the venueID is a number and the action method defaults to get method unless specified otherwise.

Remember that action methods are your methods in your controller.

Comment: Thanks - I like this approach.

Answer (score 3):

you could try adding an action default, like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "VenueDefault",
    routeTemplate: "api/venue/{venueID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Venue", action = "Venue" },
    new { venueID = @"\d+" }
);
```

Note, i've also added a constraint on the venueID so it only matches integers

Comment: Thanks! I like the constraint idea.